# Scroll/swipe by mouse on mobile not working

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, swipe, css-grid

I have a problem with scrolling/swiping a tiles. I use css grid, I've got a div container which has a several child divs.

```css
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 89%);
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50%);
overflow-x: scroll;
grid-auto-flow: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="child">child</div>
 <div class="child">child</div>
 <div class="child">child</div>
 <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

**On iphone and mobile mode in Chrome the scroll doesn't work. What's interesting, the horizontal scroll works only when i'm using arrow keys on keyboard.**

Any suggestion what's going on?

[image]

On a gif firstly I've tried swipe by mouse, then I've used keyboard.

Comment: aaand the CSS for the .child is?

Comment: nothing special, just border

Comment: children have only a green border